# What is the purpose of wiring pins 2 and 3 of a potentiometer together?

Tags: resistance, ground, potentiometer

I build a lot of audio devices - amplifiers, effects processors etc. I've been doing it for about a year and learned a lot of principles. However one thing I still don't understand is wiring pots 1 and or 2 and 3 of a potentiometer together. How is it different from using only pins 1 and or 2 and 3?

I'm talking about this sort of thing (from [here](http://pedalparts.co.uk/docs/TS-V4.pdf)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fytmQN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rather than this ([from here](http://home-wrecker.com/nurse-quacky.html)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuwTxU.png)</sup>

Please ignore resistance values, just examples.

Comment: It makes the potentiometer into a variable resistance (circuit 1) rather than a voltage divider (circuit 2)

Comment: @JImDearden That is more an explanation of why one connects a pot as a current limiter (circuit 1) vs a voltage divider (circuit 2). Once you've decided you want a current limiter, the reason for the decision to connect the wiper to the otherwise-unconnected end is as answered by Jasen.

Comment: Yes @RickBrant, Jim is right - the second example is a little misleading as it is for a different function.

Comment: @TCassa No. JlM claimed that the connection btw pins 2 and 3 "makes the potentiometer into a variable resistance". No, it does not do that! The pot is being used as a variable resistance in that circuit whether or not there's a connection btw pins 2 and 3.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It stops the resistance from going to infinity if there is dirt on the potentiometer track. (it just goes to max instead)

Comment: So is it more of a safety measure than actually having any effect on the circuit?

Comment: yeah, it helps degraded equipment stay within the design parameters. with perfect parts it would have no effect.

Comment: It is well known that the slider of a pot does not make "perfect" contact as it slides (specially wire wound pots).  Its make-and-break characteristic could cause erratic behavior in the rest of the circuit.  By connecting the slider to the other end, a minimum current is maintained (does not go to zero), as the slider breaks its contact.

Answer (score 11):

As well as the reason in the accepted answer, It also stops the unused part of the pot acting as an antenna and picking up RF noise.

Comment: how does it do that? any pick-up is still coupled into the wiper terminal.